# How can I get datepicker to work inline, but also have a year dropdown

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to have an inline date picker but with a year/month drop down.  Is that possible using JQuery Datepicker? http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: what difference would it being inline make? Please add some code or a working example :)

Comment: did you went through the link ? wat about http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Its possible.

You can try this way.

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

see **[inline datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline)**

for inline

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display inline</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

and year and month example [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
```

and merge their option